# Is there a way for a module to reference its own default export when it was assigned to an expression?

Tags: module, ecmascript-6

For example, in CommonJS:

```
var actions = module.exports = Flux.createActions({
  SubmitSignup: function(payload) {
    utils.xhr('POST', payload.url, payload.data, function(response, status){
      actions.ReceiveSignupResponse({
        response: response,
        status: status,
        receiver: payload.receiver
      });
    });
    return payload;
  },
  ReceiveSignupResponse: function(payload) {
    payload.receiver.handleSignupResponse(payload.response, payload.status);
    return payload;
  }
});
```

This exports the value of the `Flux.createActions(...)` expression as the module, and also assigns it to the local variable `actions` which is used internally so actions can refer to each-other.  Even without the multi-assignment one-liner, the value of the expression would still be available as `module.exports`.

ES6 still allows for exporting a single value for the module using `export default` and even allows for assigning a local name to that value for classes and functions:

```
export default function foo() {...}
// or
export default class Foo { ...}
```

It also allows arbitrary expressions to be exported (`export default (whatever());`)  and it allows local assignments to be exported as well (`export let actions = Flux.createActions({...});`), retaining the local name for local use,  *however*, it does **not** allow exporting an assignment expression as a default - the following are all invalid:

```
export default let actions = Flux.createActions({...});
export default (let actions = Flux.createActions({...}));
export default as actions = Flux.createActions({...});
```

Nor is there a `modules.exports` equivalent that could be used to reference the value internally (in practice, tools like babel and other transpilers will let you mix-and match CommonJS and ES6 modules as you will, so `modules.export` *will*, in fact, work, but this is non-standard, almost accidental behavior).

It is of course still perfectly possible to simply declare the local first and export it later:

```
let actions = Flux.createActions({
  SubmitSignup: function(payload) {
    utils.xhr('POST', payload.url, payload.data, function(response, status){
      actions.ReceiveSignupResponse({
        response: response,
        status: status,
        receiver: payload.receiver
      });
    });
    return payload;
  },
  ReceiveSignupResponse: function(payload) {
    payload.receiver.handleSignupResponse(payload.response, payload.status);
    return payload;
  }
});


export default actions;
```

And that's fine. It just seems like a strange incongruity that you can export and assign local names for any non-default values, including arbitrary expressions, as well as default functions and classes, just not expressions.

Is there a better way of doing this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than importing itself, I don't think there is.

The reason pretty much is that `default` is no valid identifier, so if you have you have to choose your own identifier anyway then you'll have to use the standard way of explicitly exporting:

```
let x = …;
export { x as y };
export default x;
```

Notice that `export let x = …` is only syntactic sugar for `export { x as x }`, i.e. where the local and exported name are the same, which for a default export never is the case.

Btw, default-exporting an assignment is indeed valid, you just can't use a variable declaration. Try

```
let actions;
export default (actions = Flux.createActions({...}));
```

Comment: Just to clarify one point here, if you export a class, function, or generator, then the default export would have a name.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: It might be a named function, yes, but the exported name is always just `default` - and you can also default-export anonymous functions.

Comment: Totally, not saying your answer is wrong, since the question was mostly about exporting an expression, and you are also right about unnamed functions, but `export default function foo() {}`, and the class/generator forms are in fact declarations, not expressions, and their names are available to the rest of the file, and re-assigning them will mutate a default export binding the same way it does for named exports, at least in the spec. ([Broken in Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2228))

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Oh, right, I totally forgot (or did never know?) that `default` export does take function *declarations*. Thanks for reminding me :-)